# Java get Locale from String

Tags: java

I want to get a Locale from a String and i ask myself what is the best choice between use the native API `Locale.forLanguageTag` and `LocaleUtils.toLocale` from Commons lang.

Thanks in advance for your opinion

Comment: APIs are created to provide extra functionality to already existing features. So yeah, I would go with commons.

Comment: yes but sometimes, APIs are to old (like LocaleUtils - last updated on 2010) so usage of current native API maybe most useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 7 you can use `Locale.forLanguageTag`. `LocaleUtils.toLocale` doesn't support strings like `zh-Hant`, `pt-PT`, etc.